# Solidity string array returns unexpected empty values for first 2 positions

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I have an application where I store and retrieve messages in a solidity contract. Everything works fine except that the string array is pulling the data 2 entries behind somehow. Below I have screenshotted an example where I add 5 Message structs each with "Lets post something " and then a number. All other arrays give the correct returns and if I were to try and add "Lets post something 6" and try to retrieve my string array it would return the "Lets post something 4" instead in the 6th spot. I am sure this is something obvious that I am doing wrong but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add your code to the question with text, not a picture.
And try to change the text of the message by adding the number directly to it - maybe it will become clearer

Comment: @MadJackal I added the code above and then wrote a function to get the messages by index to check each string individually and they returned normally. It is only when I return as an array that I have this error.

Comment: It seems to me that the error is not in the contract, but in the interpretation of the returned values. Can you see the raw response data not decoded by js?